# Notation in definition of Fréchet differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces, multilinear-algebra, frechet-derivative

Below I paraphrase what I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative).

Let $V,W$ be normed vector spaces, and $U\subset V$ be an open subset of $V$. A
function $f:U \to V$ is called Fréchet differentiable at $x\in U$, if there
exists a bounded linear $A$ operator such that:
$$ \lim_{\|h\| \to 0} \frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah\|_W}{\|h\|_V}=0 $$

If there exists such an operator $A$, it is unique, so we write $Df(x)=A$. 
Now, consider a function $f$ that is Fréchet differentiable at for any point of
$U$. Then, if the function
$$Df:U\to B(V,W)\; ;\; x\mapsto Df(x) $$
is continuous, then the function $f$ is said to be $C^1$.

My question is, what is the meaning of $B(V,W)$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$B(V,W)$ consists of all bounded, linear maps from $V$ to $W$. That is, $T\in B(V,W)$ means that $T:V\rightarrow W$ is linear, and $$\|Tx\|_W\leq C\|x\|_V$$ for all $x\in V.$

Comment: Thank you. In the case it is standard notation, how common is it? Do you know of any articles (links) or books that explain it?

Comment: It's pretty common. Some people may write $L(V,W)$, instead. Sometimes, the $L$ and $B$ may be written $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, as well.

Comment: Here's a link I found talking about the space of bounded linear maps and the derivative: https://www.math.wisc.edu/~seeger/522/lin.pdf

Comment: I think that $L(V,W)$ is mostly used for the set (actually a linear space itself) of all linear mappings from $V$ to $W$, and $B(V,W)$ for the subspace of bounded such.

Comment: I agree that it seems like that's generally true. I have seen books (in fact, I learned from books) that used $\mathcal{L},$ instead. I do think that it's probably better to do as you say, though, for the sake of distinguishing between them. It's probably because in the books I used, we'd rarely need notation for linear maps that weren't bounded (in the case of unbounded operators, we'd just usually say that it's unbounded operator with domain ...).